The emerging bottomBar overlaps the textField jetpack compose
I want to display a bottomBar with a button when the user has entered something into the textField, but the bottomBar appearing on the screen overlaps the textField. How can I fix this?
@Preview
@Composable
fun EditContent() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                        .padding(top = 12.dp)
                ) {
                    Button(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(vertical = 12.dp),
                        onClick = { }
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Save")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ) { scaffoldPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(scaffoldPadding)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1000.dp))
            TextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { text = it }
            )
        }
    }
}


Add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to manifest to your activity to make sure that activity window can resize correctly :
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

Then make slight changes in your code:

Use imePadding() and systemBarsPadding() to your bottomBar to make sure  it will be displayed correctly.
Replace Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1000.dp)) with Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1f)). This will make spacer that will fill all the  empty height instead of fixed 1000.dp.

@Preview
@Composable
fun EditContent() {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.White)
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                        .padding(top = 12.dp)
                        .imePadding()
                        .systemBarsPadding()
                ) {
                    Button(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(vertical = 12.dp),
                        onClick = { }
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "Save")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ) { scaffoldPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .padding(scaffoldPadding)
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        ) {

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1f))

            TextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { text = it }
            )
        }
    }
}


I set the height for spacer to 1000 dp so as not to insert all the content that is on my screen into the sample code. I did not replace height(1000.dp) with weight(1f), but the rest of the modifier did not help me solve the problem.

<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

or
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

try this code in your manifest file.
